# streamcorrupted exception while reading back multiple objects

Tags: java, serialization

I wrote 2 objects to a file but when I try to read back the objects written it throws an exception in the desrialize method. It works fine when I write a single object but fails with 2 objects written to the file and the exception is thrown while reading the second object.

```
File_obj.Serialize_object(d, "/home/dasman/doc/serobj1.bin");
File_obj.Serialize_object(b, "/home/dasman/doc/serobj1.bin");
File_obj.deSerialize_object("/home/dasman/doc/serobj1.bin");



java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid type code: AC
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1373)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:368)
at Testpackage.File_obj.deSerialize_object(File_obj.java:242)
at File_test.main(File_test.java:28)
```

The method for serialize and deserialize in File_obj class are here

```
public static void Serialize_object(Object obj,String filename){
    File a = new File(filename);
    ObjectOutputStream out = null;
    try{
     out = new ObjectOutputStream(new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(a,true)));
    }catch(IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try{

    out.writeObject(obj);
    out.close();
    }catch(IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
    public static void deSerialize_object(String filename){
    File a = new File(filename);
    int objcount = 0;
    ObjectInputStream in = null;
    try{
     in = new ObjectInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(a)));
    }catch(IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Serializable_test obj1 = null;
    try{
    while(true){    

    obj1 = (Serializable_test) in.readObject();
    objcount++;
    System.out.println("The object area is :" + obj1.get_area());

    }
    }catch(EOFException e){
        System.out.println("END of object files reached objects read :" + objcount);
        //in.close();
    }catch(IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }catch(ClassNotFoundException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


}
```

Comment: Despite making a mistake over the overwrite, Bohemian offered some good tips on how to solve this.  If those suggestions do not work for you, I suggest you post an [SSCCE](http://pscode.org/sscce.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't append to a file that was created via ObjectOutputStream. You have to rewrite the whole file. ObjectOutputStream writes a header that ObjectInputStream won't understand if it reoccurs inside the file.

You can however write multiple objects to the *same* ObjectOutputStream, and read them back, contrary to what is stated in other answers here.

Answer (score 1):

What's your question here? You are writing two objects into the same file - of course the second one will be appended to the first - java can't handle this!

To fix, either:

- A) Write to different files, or
- B) Put the objects in an array or Collection (eg List) and write that to the one file and deserialize the array/Collection and retrieve your objects from there

Comment: But if you  notice I have FileOutputStream(a,true)) so it should append to the file right?

Comment: "You are writing two objects into the same file - of course the second one will overwrite the first." Nu-uh - Not when the `FileOutputStream(a,true)` ..is set to append.

Comment: Incorrect. Java can indeed handle this, as long as it is done within the same ObjectInputStream. Otherwise you get this error.

Answer (score 1):

The deserialization routine can only only re-constitute one object (or object graph) at a time. It assumes that the serialized content being read in only pertains to a single object and treats the file containing data from two objects as corrupted..

Comment: hmm so what if i write an array of objects in one go without closing the channel? can it reconstitute all the objects then?.

Comment: Yes. The entire object graph would be serialized. That was Bohemian's 'B' suggestion.

Comment: -1. Completely incorrect. You can write as many objects as you like. But you have to to write them all with the same ObjectOutputStream. See my answer.